# Double pointer for creating an array of objects (Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdd1)

Tags: c++, pointers

I'd be very grateful if someone could shed some insight on the following:

I have an Image class. I want to dynamically allocate some memory for 3 objects of said class. My approach is -

```
    Image **st0 = new Image*[3];

    for (char j = 0; j<= 2; j++)
    {
         *st0[j].doSomething();
    }
```

My thinking is that (*st0) returns the pointer to the pointer of Images, and then the [] appended on the end will select each successive Image. But I get an error about accessing uninitialized memory. (Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdd1)

When I step through this with a debugger, I see that st0 is assigned to some location in memory, but when I step into the entity within, it contains 0xcdcdcdcd. What's the dealio?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Image **st0 = new Image*[3];
```

This allocates space for storing three pointers to objects of class `Image`.  It does not allocate memory for those objects.  There are two options for what to do about this:

1) Allocate an array of objects instead:

```
Image *st0 = new Image[3];
```

2) Allocate the objects:

```
Image **st0 = new Image*[3];
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    st0[i] = new Image;
}
```

The first option is simpler, while the second lets you allocate and de-allocate `Image`s on an as-needed basis.  Which one is better depends on the rest of your program.

Comment: "better" implies that one or both of them is *good*. That's simply not the case. Direct use of raw `new` and `delete` is something even experts avoid whenever possible. Advising a beginner about the "right" way to do it is just helping them shoot themselves in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using dynamic allocation purely out of masochism (or something on that order), you're much better off avoiding it.

I'd rather use a small class that uses a `std::vector` to store the data, and provides an operator overload to support 2D addressing into that data:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    std::vector<T> data;
    size_t cols;
public:
    Matrix(size_t X, size_t Y) : cols(x), data(x*y) {}
    T &operator()(size_t x, size_t Y) {
        return data[Y*cols+x];
    }
};
```

Then just instantiate that for the size of matrix you want and use your data:

```
Matrix<Image> st0(3, 3);

st0(0, 0) = whatever;
st1(1, 1) = something_else;
// etc.
```

Comment: I'm a relative newcomer, so rather than jump to all the nice other libraries and features (I see std::vector recommended a lot, but I've never used it)...I want to first learn how to pull all the right levers myself.

Comment: @user2864293: There's plenty of time for that later...much later! Seriously, implementing something like `vector` (even sort of close to well) on your own is a truly [difficult task](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html).

Comment: What's masochistic about dynamic allocation? Are there other risks besides memory leaks? So long as I make sure I delete all the new stuff, I'm safe...right?

Comment: Memory leaks are an obvious problem--but making sure you delete everything you allocate is decidedly non-trivial. Just for example code as trivial as: `T *t = new T; ++*t; delete t;` *already* has a potential memory leak. Yes, I used `delete`--but it can leak anyway! I'll repeat: doing dynamic memory management correctly really is a non-trivial task.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd care to elaborate on where the leak potential is? =) 

Is it because the program can be interrupted or otherwise stopped after the "new" usage, but before a delete can take place?

Comment: @user2864293: Yes. To be more specific, it can throw an exception.